# Testing MySQL database with node API locally

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl

I created a simple MySQL database and hosted it on my local machine using XAMP.
I then create an api using node and express js. Testing using Postman everything seems to work, however if I try to use the API from an external app I get errors related to SSL Certificate. Following a tutorial on Medium I managed to get the error go away but still can't test the api I always get these errors:

> **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**
>
> **app.js:18 Request failed TypeError: Failed to fetch**.

This is my api

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

//local host port
const port = 8080;


//read the certificate
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('../security/test-privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../security/my-certificate.pem')
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//databse info
var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'localhost',
  user:'admin',
  password:'password',
  database:'tutorial'
});

//connect to the database
db.connect((err) => {
  if(err){
    console.log('error',);
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('database working');
})

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
  res.send('running database');
});


//get students
app.get('/api/getstudent', (req, responce)=> {
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM `students` ORDER BY `students`.`name` ASC';
  
  db.query(sql, (err, res)=> {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    const str = JSON.stringify(res);

    responce.send('retuning data' + str);
  });
});

//insert student
app.post('/api/inserstudent', (req, responce)=> {
  const sql = "INSERT INTO students (name, age) VALUES ('test-student', 15)";
  
  db.query(sql, (err, res)=> {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('inserted');
    responce.send('retuning data');
  });
});
  

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
  .listen(port, () => {
      console.log('server running at ' + port)
  })
```

this is how I am making the request

```
init = () =>{
  const req = 'https://localhost:8080/api/getstudent';
  fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response); 
    }).catch(function(error) {  
      console.log('Request failed', error)  
    });
}
```

and this is how chrome shows the page if I navigate to the api url

[image]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your certificate is missing the subject alternative name and the certification authority is not trusted. (There is little reason to use HTTPs on the localhost. If you just want to test the API, do it with regular HTTP)

Comment: using just http request I get this error `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/getstudent' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`